# Wordpress Multi Pages- The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: html, wordpress, apache, web

I install wordpress for my server. I can access without any problem. I need a different wordpress page. But I have only one server. 
I install again wordpress in /var/www/voltran. (I also create voltran folder under /var/www/html/ and linked it like voltran -> /var/www/voltran/.

I am trying to connect as http://104.240.163.37/voltran. But it doesnt work.

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested wordpress installations is not the best idea ever. 
instead of having an installation in /var/www/html/ and another in /var/www/html/voltran

Make something like:
/var/www/html/wp1
/var/www/html/voltran

However,  this doesn't mean that it won't work, nested installations should still work.

Your main server IP does not even redirect to your first installation,
but you said

> I install wordpress for my server. I can access without any problem.

So can you please give the link you're using to access that installation?

Also, did you use the same database for both installations?

I believe your issue is not programming/WP related. it's probably that you need to setup your webserver correctly.